# HTML iframes, one cancels other?

Tags: html, iframe

I have two iframes, both of which are to the same page. Very little has been done to either, other than one having an `onload` function set. However, when I put them in the page, only the first one will load. If I switch the order they appear in, the second always fails to show up. Both work perfectly by themselves. Here is the code for the table with the frames in it:

```
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="gameFrame">
<td>
<iframe id="gameFrame" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"/>
</td>
<tr>
<tr id="controls">
<td>
<iframe id="goalFinder" onload="getGoal()" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What is causing the second frame not to show up, and how can I fix it?

Comment: No problem with two `iframe` elements on the same page as such, so the problem is elsewhere, quite possibly in the JavaScript code, which was not disclosed.

Comment: `<iframe> !== "self closing tag"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close your `<iframe>`. It's not a self-closing element.

```
 <iframe id="gameFrame" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"></iframe>
<iframe id="goalFinder" onload="getGoal()" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"></iframe>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GvQ38/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a closing tag for each iframe instead of />

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <iframe id="gameFrame" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"></iframe>
            </td>
        <tr>
        <tr id="controls">
            <td>
            <iframe id="goalFinder" onload="getGoal()" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```